# Having the same MSE, RMSE, MAE for Ridge and RandomForest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have used the given code to predict values, however, I have landed the same score, for all 3 metrics, while having different metrics for all other models.

```
def metrics(valid, pred):
  mse = mean_squared_error(valid, pred)
  rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(valid, pred))
  mae = mean_absolute_error(valid,pred)
  return mse, rmse, made

model = Ridge().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

df_models_temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Ridge', *metrics(y_test, y_pred)]], columns=['Model Name', 'MSE', 'RMSE', 'MAE'])
df_models = df_models.append(df_models_temp, ignore_index=True)

clf = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

df_models_temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Random Forest', *metrics(y_test, y_pred)]], columns=['Model Name', 'MSE', 'RMSE', 'MAE'])
df_models = df_models.append(df_models_temp, ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are still using the Ridge to make prediction for the RandomForest, code should be like:

```
model = Ridge().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

df_models_temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Ridge', *metrics(y_test, y_pred)]], columns=['Model Name', 'MSE', 'RMSE', 'MAE'])
df_models = df_models.append(df_models_temp, ignore_index=True)

clf = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)
# Here predict with clf not model
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are actually due to typos; flag them as such instead.